# How to fix this database query?

Tags: java, html, jsp, cassandra, cql

```
    // gets user details from jsp form
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    //String forename = request.getParameter("forename");

    // sets new user
    User us = new User();
    us.setCluster( cluster );

    //checks user is valid
    boolean isValid = us.IsValidUser( username, password );
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    System.out.println("Session in servlet " + session);

    // sets the user details so it can be displayed during session
    session.setAttribute("userID", username);


    sess = cluster.connect("instagrim");
    ResultSet results = sess.execute ("SELECT first_name FROM userprofiles WHERE login = 'shadowsurge'"  );

    for (Row row : results) 
    {
        String userName = (row.getString("first_name"));
        request.setAttribute("name", userName);
    }
```

The above code is the part I'm working on right now. I finally managed to read data from my Cassandra database BUT this is only when I specify a certain condition such as `"SELECT first_name FROM userprofiles WHERE login = 'shadowsurge'"`

I'm trying to create a user profile, so obviously the above code isn't suitable as I need the query to grab the data that's related to the user who logged in, not just grab the data for one user regardless of who is logged in.

Anyone able to help with this? Basically, I want the query to grab the `first_name` which is associated with the currently logged in user, but I can't seem to get that to happen.

Comment: So you never tried the naive version `"SELECT first_name FROM userprofiles WHERE login = '" + username + "'"`? If this works, then use a "[prepared statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)" instead.

Comment: Wow that was so obvious, why didn't I do that. 

First time using Java, JSP, cassandra etc. I think I'm over thinking half of it  but thank you so much! Can I ask though, what's the difference between this way and doing it in a prepared statement? I'm assuming there's some sort of advantage to using a prepared statement or is it just the better habit to get into?

Comment: Think about your query and what will happen if I register myself as `"'; DROP TABLE users;--`. A prepared statement avoids SQL injection.

Comment: Right, fair point. Like I said, completely new to all this, not my kinda thing. So I'm assuming it's also better not to have that in a JSP file but inside a java class instead?

Comment: @Tom, you raise some good points that the OP definitely needs to hear.  But CQL != SQL, so the link you provided isn't going to help much for someone working with Cassandra.

Answer (score 2):

The DataStax Cassandra Java Driver documentation has a section titled [Four Simple Rules For Coding With The Driver](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/fourSimpleRules.html) that you should definitely read through.  In this doc, the section on Prepared Statements describes the advantages of using them:

> Using prepared statements provides multiple benefits. A prepared
>   statement is parsed and prepared on the Cassandra nodes and is ready
>   for future execution. When binding parameters, only these (and the
>   query id) are sent over the wire. These performance gains add up when
>   using the same queries (with different parameters) repeatedly.

In any case, for you to set up a Prepared Statement with Cassandra, you will need to slightly alter your code.

```
sess = cluster.connect("instagrim");

//create a Prepared Statement from your session
PreparedStatement statement = sess.prepare("SELECT first_name FROM userprofiles WHERE login=?");

//create a Bound Statement from your above statement object
BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(statement);

//pass your boundStatement to your sess.execute while binding username to it.
ResultSet results = sess.execute(boundStatement.bind(username));
```

Comment: This is good to know! I feel like there's a lot more info about SQL on the net compared to CQL, or maybe I just haven't looked in the right places.

But yeah, thanks a lot for that, I'll definitely be reading over the links you both provided

Answer (score 0):

What is login in your query? 
You can try to change your query to something like:
 `ResultSet results = sess.execute ("SELECT first_name FROM userprofiles WHERE login = ' + username + '"  );`  if login is the same as the username in the userprofiles table.